# Any options for logging client side errors in a Dynamics 365 portal site?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-portals

I am working with a Dynamics 365 Customer Self-Service portal running alongside a Dynamics 365 CRM online instance and I'm having issues with customers using the site.  I've read the docs on how to enable diagnostic logging with Azure blob storage, and that is fine for some situations, but I believe some of the problems are being caused by client-side javascript or other browser-related errors.  Is there any good option for capturing and logging these types of errors back in CRM or elsewhere?  I have also thought about using a web template with liquid code to send something back to CRM, which I have done in other areas of the portal, but it's possible the problem is that the portal can't communicate back to CRM.

I'm feeling stuck here, I don't want to show javascript errors to the customer, but if the original error involved not being able to communicate with the CRM instance, then how do I log anything?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would not collect any error logs within Production system for many reasons.

For that purpose we have many telemetry solutions like [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-sample-mscrm), which can be used to capture all handled client side exceptions on its own Azure blobs. Though these talk about CRM, it can be used for any applications including Portals.

[Capturing explicit exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-exceptions#reporting-exceptions-explicitly)

[Jason Lattimer Application Insights](https://jlattimer.blogspot.com/2018/06/d365-application-insights-javascript.html?m=1)